# How to compare range within a number in excel

Tags: excel

following is data on which i'm working :

```
     A       B      C    D   E   F      G 
1  Roll No  Name    m1  m2  m3  m4  ResuLt
2    1      Raman   40  30  55  80
3    2      Priya   20  40  50  99  
4    3      Gouri   60  66  84  44
```

I want to get result out of two values pass or fail.
criteria of result :- if value in C2:F2 is less than 33 then display fail otherwise pass in G2 cell

can anybody tell me formula for above task?

Comment: =IF(OR(C2<33;D2<33;E2<33;F2<33);"fail";"pass") ?

Comment: can i use range instead of using cell names because if there are more number of cells then it becomes tedious task??

Comment: `=IF(MIN(C2:F2)<33,"Fail","Pass")` - If the minimum value in the range is less than 33, they've failed.

Comment: @JamieDunstan, could you post your comment as an answer so the OP can, hopefully, mark it as such? This will stop it appearing in the Unanswered list.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - good point. I will do this now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(MIN(C2:F2)<33,"Fail","Pass")
```

If the minimum value in the range of scores is less than 33, they've failed.

Comment: Thanks. Reading Meta, questions answered in comments are a bit of an issue. Now it's just up to @user47288 to mark it as an answer and the cycle will be complete - lots of :) faces all round.